# Provide a way to upload images from android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It seems there's no way to upload images from the App. This can come really handy at different instances and would be a great addition.

Comment: I *also* yearn for the day when I can quickly attach pictures of whatever I happen to be eating/drinking into MSO posts.